# Is there a way to read information from a spreadsheet and match and add info to music files?

Tags: excel, sorting, metadata, file-organization

In a small project my friends and I are collecting songs and song metadata such as lyrics, song writer, composer, year, etc... information to a wide collection of Libyan folksmusic. The obtained files are mostly recordings in weddings and other occasions. So the copywrites are legit.

We decided to match the song file name (say `.mp3` or `.wav`) with a corresponding cell in an excel sheet and add the information, including the lyrics (all in Arabic) in that row. Example:
file:'**LibyanSong**.mp3' located in a given file, in Excel, the rows are something like:

| File name | Singer | Composer | Lyrics | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| '**LibyanSong**' | 'Shadi Jabal' | 'Ali Shaalia' | 'Lorem Ipsum...' | 1953 |

I would like to know if there is a way to add these information to the music files by looping, matching and then adding the information, so that it saves us the cumbersome job of doing that manually (files are around 1200 and counting)

P.S. I have a mediocre background in python and can operate MATLAB well.

Comment: What an interesting project! Yes you can do this. You just need to find a library or tool that lets you write to mp3 attributes. Let me do some googling to find one.

Comment: Here's a python package that writes to mp3. https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ you just need another python package that reads from excel (CSV is often easier). Is all of the information already in this excel file, or are you about to start data entry now?

Comment: Another option for example is to build an excel formula on each line that results in the required command line, then just copy paste that and run it. For example the python cmd line example is  `eyeD3 -a Integrity -A "Humanity Is The Devil" -t "Hollow" -n 2 song.mp3`. You can build that command line using excel formulas, paste them into a batch file and run them all. This would be the quickest and simplest solution, provided it can handle special charavters